# Error decompiling recovered .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, class, decompiler

I wanted to import a java program I had written in jgrasp to eclipse and what I tried doing wasn't working out so I decided to delete the file from eclipse thinking I would still have it in the folder from which I imported the file from. However, i soon found out this just deleted my program all together. I used EaseUs data recovery to recover the file I deleted but it only was able to recover the .class file. I read up on how to decompile a .class file back into a .java file and I decided to go to a site called javadecompilers.com. I tested it on other projects I have and it worked perfectly. I attached the .class file and it decompiled it back into a .java file. However, when I try attaching the class files which I recovered, it doesn't work and I get this error:

Can't load the class specified: 
org.benf.cfr.reader.util.CannotLoadClassException: HangmanGame.class - org.benf.cfr.reader.util.ConfusedCFRException: Magic != Cafebabe for class file 'HangmanGame.class'

If i open the class file in notepad I can clearly see that it isn't empty so why am I getting this error for all my recovered programs. Is there any way I can convert them back to .java files? Thanks.

Comment: There are decompilers available, both free and commercial, and often the better ones are the more expensive ones, but they're not perfect, they certainly don't give you readable variables, but it can't hurt to try one of the free ones. If it doesn't work then probably your best bet is to re-write the code.

Answer (score 0):

The recovered class files are corrupted. The first four bytes of a class file are hex: CA, FE, BA, BE = decimal: 202, 254, 186, 190 = text: Êþº¾ . If you open with a binary editor (you can use binary mode in jGRASP), that's what you should see at the start. If you're lucky the recovered files just have extra bytes at the start. You could back them up, open in a binary editor, search for "Êþº¾", and if found cut off everything in front of that. If that is the case, there may also be extra bytes at the end. Decompilers may or may not be able to handle that. There is probably some decompiler or class file viewer that can help, or you could modify an open source class file scanner to find the correct end point.